# websocat / wscat save a new file per seconds

Tags: stdout, socket

This question is about saving a wss:// stream into multiple files... while execution (NOT AFTER)

EXAMPLE :

```
websocat "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@depth" > /path/$(date +%s).txt
```

This command receive TONS of new line per second....

This command create a file with the date in unix timestamp but will continue to save in the same file until I ctrl+c .....

I don't want to bloat into a 1 super large file.... I want that the stdout is saved ( in multiple files)

example

1652209720.txt will have 30 lines

1652209721.txt will have 10 lines

etc

I tried to create a .sh with `while command do ....` but I receive the stdout in the shell instead of the new file...

how can I do this ?

- note: I know more php that bash scripting...
  EDIT the full .sh ------

  #!/bin/bash

  while websocat "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@depth"
  do
  read line
  echo $line >> /Users/jinto/Downloads/d/$(date +%s).stub
  done

Comment: Please share the .sh you created. It might be a whole of a lot easier to tell you what to fix in your code, instead of trying to create something from scratch.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I edited the question with the .sh I tried... note that I know more php than bash scripting. how can I "pass" each new message into a file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pipe the output of `websocat`, something along these lines (note the `|` at the end of the `websocat`:

```
websocat "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@depth" |
while read line
do
    echo $line >> /Users/jinto/Downloads/d/$(date +%s).stub
done
```

Comment: thanks, it's exactly what I was looking for ;)